# About the Exponential function

Tags: geometry, analysis, functions

Consider function $y=a^x$, $a>1$, and we need to show that

$$\frac{2(a-1)}{(a+1)} < \ln(a) < -1 + \sqrt{2a-1}$$

My idea is to use $y=a^x = \exp{(x\ln a)}$, then find the derivative of $y$ at $x=0$, which is $\ln a$.

But I don’t know how to continue beyond this.

Any idea on using geometry or something to prove it?

Comment: Hint for the lower bound: $\ln a = 2\tanh ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{{a - 1}}{{a + 1}}} \right)$.

Comment: For the lower bound, set $f(a) = \sqrt {2a - 1}  - 1 - \log a$ and show that $f'(a)>0$ for $a>1$, i.e., $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing. In particular, $f(a)>f(1)=0$ for $a>1$.

Comment: Thanks Gary for help. I am wondering on the a-1 and a+1 term

Comment: $0<\frac{a-1}{a+1}<1$ for $a>1$. Can you see that $\tanh^{-1}(x)>x$ for $0<x<1$?

Answer (score 2):

For LHS, set

$$f(a) = \ln a - \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1} = \ln a + \frac{2}{a+1} - 2, a> 1$$

Then we have

$$f'(a) = \frac{1}{a} - \frac{2}{(a+1)^2} = \frac{(a+1)^2 - 2a}{a(a+1)^2} = \frac{a^2 + 1}{a(a+1)^2} > 0$$

So $f$ is increasing when $a> 1$, and this means $f(a) > f(1) = 0$. So we have LHS of the inequality.

For RHS, set $x = -1 + \sqrt{2a-1} > 0$ since $a>1$, so we have

$$a = \frac{1}{2}(x+1)^2 + \frac{1}{2} = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2$$

By Taylor series of $e^x$, we have

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + ... + \frac{1}{n!}x^n + ... >1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 = a$$

And this means

$$e^x = e^{-1 + \sqrt{2a-1}} > a$$

So we have

$$-1 + \sqrt{2a-1} > \ln a$$

which is exactly RHS.